# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Application can run in a console too?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm confused about the new ASP.NET Core Web Application option when creating a new application in Visual Studio 2019. I originally wanted to start off by creating a RESTful Service. I found YouTube videos on how to do this, and the way to do it is by selecting ASP.NET Core Web Application template, and then selecting the API template on the second window. When I run the app, it runs in a browser.

But when I look at the project properties, it shows Output Type = Console Application. The Debug tab of the Properties window shows that I can uncheck the option "Launch browser" and select Launch option to be Project. When I run it under these options, it runs in a Console window.

What am I actually doing here? Am I running this RESTful service in a host console without having to write a console host myself?
This is not really a web application. Am I correct in saying this? Even though my first selection is to choose ASP.NET Core ***Web*** Application template.
I'm a little confused about the name of the template.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mind sharing that youtube url ? Also, you can take a look at this [SO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085806/what-is-the-difference-between-iwebhost-webhostbuilder-buildwebhost) in terms of [generic-host for aspnetcore 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: @nwpie https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfMsUmQX_IQ