# Difference between IHostBuilder ConfigureServices and IWebHostBuilder ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Is this just nesting?  ConfigureServices inside of IWebHostBuilder can use both the parent IHostBuilder AND the internally registered services?  Or the other way around?

Do they end up being the same DI Register?  Is there something more to this I don't realize?

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
        webBuilder.ConfigureServices(services => {});
    }
.ConfigureServices(services => {});
```

Comment: Check source here https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/HostBuilder.cs,3f90967d8ad602a4,references

Comment: [`IHostBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)  works for  sharing state between components during the host building process its an extension of `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostBuilder`  on the other hand [`IWebHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhost?view=aspnetcore-2.0)  Runs a web application and block the calling thread until host shutdown it does other stuff as well.

Comment: [Nice thread you can read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085806/what-is-the-difference-between-iwebhost-webhostbuilder-buildwebhost)

Comment: I think the replies in comment are very helpful to some extent.  But my question isn't on the difference between IHost and IWebHost.  It is about whether or not there is any known sharing between their DI Containers.  IE: A WebHost runs inside a Host, so does the WebHost also have access to dependencies registered with the parent Host?  Or the other way around?  Nkosi's code link makes it seem like no, but I don't know the inner workings of every Microsoft extension class and external factors.

Comment: So if you are interested on inner machanism I would suggest you to check official descrption for that. You could start from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) then move to your point of interest.