# dotnet core 5. Cant solve runtime error: The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am doing a dotnet course and in the EF module the author seems to be piecing recordings from different times... the code changes without the change being demonstrated and I got stuck finally and dont know how to proceed. Would appreciate help.

I am attempting to run the program from the command prompt:

```
PS I:\Users\Ron\Projects\MVC\DutchTreat> dotnet run /seed
```

And getting this error:

```
The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied.
A usable launch profile could not be located.
Unhandled exception. System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DutchTreat.Data.Entities.Product]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
    at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type propertyType)
    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, TCollection& value)
    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    at DutchTreat.Data.DutchSeeder.Seed() in I:\Users\Ron\Projects\MVC\DutchTreat\Data\DutchSeeder.cs:line 34
    at DutchTreat.Program.RunSeeding(IHost host) in I:\Users\Ron\Projects\MVC\DutchTreat\Program.cs:line 41
    at DutchTreat.Program.Main(String[] args) in I:\Users\Ron\Projects\MVC\DutchTreat\Program.cs:line 26
```

This is a part of my project which I think is relevant (but I might be missing some files):

```cs
using DutchTreat.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;

namespace DutchTreat.Data
{
    public class DutchContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public DutchContext(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:DutchContextDb"]);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasData(new Order()
                {
                    Id=1,
                    OrderDate=DateTime.UtcNow,
                    OrderNumber="12345"
                });
        }


    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DutchTreat.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace DutchTreat.Data
{
    
    public class DutchSeeder
    {
        private readonly DutchContext _ctx;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

        public DutchSeeder(DutchContext ctx,IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
            _env = env;
        }

        public void Seed()
        {
            _ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

            if (!_ctx.Products.Any())
            {
                //Need to create sample data
                var filePath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath,"Data/art.json");
                var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                var products = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Product>>(json);

                _ctx.Products.AddRange(products);

                var order = new Order()
                {
                    OrderDate = DateTime.Today,
                    OrderNumber = "10000",
                    Items = new List<OrderItem>()
                    {
                        new OrderItem()
                        {
                            Product=products.First(),
                            Quantity=5,
                            UnitPrice=products.First().Price
                        }
                    }
                };
                _ctx.Orders.Add(order);

                _ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DutchTreat.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.IO;

    

namespace DutchTreat
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var host = BuildWebHost(args);
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            if (args.Length == 1 && args[0].ToLower() =="/seed")
            {
                RunSeeding(host);
                return;
            }

            host.Run();           

        }

        private static void RunSeeding(IHost host)
        {
            var scopeFactory = host.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
            
            using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            { 
                var seeder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DutchSeeder>();
                seeder.Seed();
            }   

        }


        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085806/what-is-the-difference-between-iwebhost-webhostbuilder-buildwebhost

        //public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        //    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        //        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        //        .Build();
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(SetupConfiguration)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });

        private static void AddConfiguration(HostBuilderContext ctx, 
            IConfigurationBuilder bldr)
        {
            bldr.Sources.Clear();

            bldr.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }
        private static void SetupConfiguration(HostBuilderContext ctx, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            // Removing the default configuration options
            builder.Sources.Clear();

            builder.AddJsonFile("config.json", false, true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using DutchTreat.Controllers;
using DutchTreat.Data;
using DutchTreat.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;


namespace DutchTreat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<DutchContext>();
            services.AddTransient<DutchSeeder>();
            services.AddTransient<IMailService,NullMailService>();

            //services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            //app.UseDefaultFiles();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.MapRazorPages();
                        cfg.MapControllerRoute("Default",
                                                "/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                                                new { controller = "App", action = "Index" });

                    });

            //If I understand correctly the bellow is for making an API avaialble without
            //having a webpage
            //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            //{
            //    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            //    {
            //        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //    });
            //});
        }
    }
}
```

**launchSettings.json:**

```json
{
    "profiles": {
        "IIS Express": {
            "commandName": "IISExpress",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
            }
        }
    },
    "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8888",
            "sslPort": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .NET 5 reached End-Of-Life 6 months ago. Odd versions of .NET Core are single-year versions. The current Long-Term-Support version is .NET 6

Comment: `I am doing a dotnet course` you should find a course that targets supported .NET Core versions

Comment: As for the error itself it complains that the JSON file is wrong. Please post only enough code to reproduce the problem. The relevant parts are the JSON contents, the definition of `Product` and  `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Product>>(json);` The error says that the contents of that file aren't a `Product` array.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks. The course started in a supported version of 3.1 and then switched to 5 in the middle and I just want to finish covering the material.

Comment: Regarding your second comment. thank you for that too. I found that the project file ART.json didnt include the definitions of the products. I corrected that and am not longer getting that error. 

I am still getting:
PS I:\Users\Ron\Projects\MVC\DutchTreat> dotnet run /seed
The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied.
A usable launch profile could not be located.
PS I:\Users\Ron\Projects\MVC\DutchTreat>

What does that mean please?

Comment: The seeding worked actually. I just dont have a clue why I am getting the error. What profile is missing?